# How to convert the following R code to Python code

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

The code drops the columns that are not required from the table:

```
inputData <- inputData[,!(colnames(inputData) %in% c('col1','col2',''))]
```

Need help converting this line to python, I'm struggling with it as I'm fairly new to python ;-;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need translation to third-party Pandas which unlike R, data frames are  not standard library objects in Python, consider [**`Index.isin`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) to replace `%in%` and tilde negation operator, `~`, to replace `!`:

```py
inputData = inputData[
    inputData.columns[~inputData.columns.isin(['col1','col2',''])]
]
```

Alternatively, try [**`Index.difference`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```py
inputData = inputData[
    inputData.columns.difference(['col1','col2',''])
]
```